# Adjective for "terrified yet calm and capable"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is an adjective to describe the duality of a first responder (such as an EMT responding to a terrorist attack) who is terrified for the wounded, yet simultaneously calm, detached, and capable enough to give aid?

Comment: 'Terrified' is a bit inconsistent with 'calm'. Are you looking for (which is the way everyone is answering) 'calm in a situation that is terrify _ing_ to most people'?

Comment: I'm a fan of *steely*, meaning: "Coldly determined; hard"

Comment: Shouldn't the word _terrified_ be replaced with _horrified_? The former means _filled with fear_ (I assume the OP wants to say the EMT's afraid they'll all die or suffer through treatment & recovery & post-recovery), but the latter means [MW3UDE] _**horror** 1a: a painful emotion of intense fear, dread, or dismay_, which includes the _fear_ in _terrified_.

Comment: Normally the word we use is, "Brave".

Comment: *Equanimity*, listed in an answer below, is an excellent choice. Two more words come to mind: *resilient/fortitude*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following don't explicitly satisfy the *terrified* criteria; they are instead words that represent calmness under *pressure*. Terror could be construed to be a form of pressure.

[Equanimity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equanimity) is defined as:

> evenness of mind especially **under stress**

Its adjective would be *equanimous*.

Its synonym, [sangfroid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sangfroid), is defined as:

> self-possession or imperturbability especially **under strain**

While the dictionary does not note its adjectival properties, you can probably use it as one. A *sangfroid calm* is a reasonably common phrase.

[Unflappable](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unflappable) is similarly defined:

> having or showing calmness **in a crisis**

Comment: An interesting case of idioms that don't have the same meaning across different languages - 'sangfroid' translates to 'cold blood', which means something entirely different in English.  I suppose they do both have the element of calmness under stress, but 'sangfroid' lacks the sinister aspect of 'cold blood'.

Comment: while "cold blood" means something different, "coolheaded" has the correct meaning.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman would the translation of "cold blood" mean something similar to the phrase, "ice water in her veins" rather than "he was murdered in cold blood"? As in, one who has ice water in their veins are indeed unflappable. Or are those two phrases also connected?

Comment: Bah, should've kept reading. @Zoot answered below and made a direct connection between "ice water in their veins" and sang froid.

Comment: Unflappable misses the mark. I don't think the injured or the injurers are bent on disrupting the EMT's composure, such as by making wise cracks or hurling personal invectives--albeit that people in agitated coma can get mighty rowdy with the tongue--however, comatose individuals generally don't inspire much in the way of commiserative feelings to begin with.

Answer (score 9):

They can be described as **mechanical**, **stoic**, **businesslike**, **calm under pressure**, or **having icewater in their veins**.

In French, this term is "*sang-froid*".

Comment: Sangfroid has been smuggled into English as well.

Comment: English doesn't **smuggle** vocabulary; it **steals** it in back alley muggings.

Comment: Then goes through pockets for loose grammar?

Comment: @Byte56: Vocabulary ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Nicoll#.22The_Purity_of_the_English_Language.22

Comment: @Byte56 - Oh come now, everyone knows English doesn't bother with grammar.

Answer (score 7):

The adjectives *calm*, *composed* and *equanimous* already have the connotation of one being possibly in a terrible situation.

Comment: I really like "composed".

Answer (score 6):

I like **stoic** for the given situation:

> A person who can endure pain or hardship without showing their feelings or complaining.

Comment: Stoic lacks compassion though. It wouldn't fit well with the example of first responders given.

Answer (score 3):

I like *resolute*. Definition from Google:

> Admirably purposeful, determined, and unwavering

Answer (score 2):

Someone commented on the OP's question with *[steely](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=define%20steely#hl=en&tbo=u&q=steely&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=MN63UMWYJOmoiQLwwICoBg&ved=0CC0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b5a378127ae23922&bpcl=39314241&biw=1920&bih=879)* and I think that best fits the situation and usage that you describe.

```
steel·y
adjective /ˈstēlē/ 
steelier, comparative; steeliest, superlative
Resembling steel in color, brightness, or strength
- a steely blue
Coldly determined; hard
- there was a steely edge to his questions
```

Answer (score 1):

self-possessed

self-constrained

intrepid

Comment: Um, this has nothing to do with *terrified*.

Comment: Sorry, but there is authority behind those examples. This has nothing to do... is syntactically incorrect: ...those have nothing to do... is correct, unless your are saying that your comment has nothing to do....  The OP question did not ask for terrified's definition. It asked for suggestions for expressing calm in the grips of fear and sympathy.

Comment: @lex 1. I agree with your last point. 2. Comments are temporary and cannot be edited, so there is no use pointing out grammar and spelling erors. 3. In Daniel's sentence, "this" refers to the answer as a whole (singular), not the three suggestions (plural). 4. The real problem with your answer is that it is too short: lacks discussion or explanation, or even a citation. If there is an authority behind those examples, it is on you to demonstrate the fact in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Scared yet still willing and capable to do the right thing is pretty much the definition of bravery.

Comment: The main problem with *brave* (*courageous, valiant*, etc.) is they don't particularly imply "calm and capable". Just as others in that general area *(dauntless, bold, fearless, intrepid)* tend not to imply "terrified".

Answer (score 0):

"Duality" of first reponder seems a bit nebulous. It's almost as if the word you seek is something akin to *bedside manner*: perhaps, *gerney-side-fortitudinous*; or *trauma-scene-innured*; perhaps even *reassuring* or *self-assured*; or just *composed*.

Comment: You mean [*gurney*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurney), right?