# Are there metaphoric English expressions meaning “keeping composure at a fatal moment, never panicky”?

Tags: idioms, metaphors

We have a Japanese old saying, “俎板の上の鯉－manaita no ueno koi, a carp laid on a chopping block” for describing (1) a critical situation you cannot avoid, and (2) a person who is self-poised at such a critical moment.

This metaphor comes from the legend that carp is still and composed unlike other fish, like eel when laid on a chopping board. I think it corresponds to the spirit of ‘葉隠-Hagakure’, the Bushido’s bible written by Yamamoto Tsunetomo, a senior samurai in Saga-Nabeshima fief in 1716, in which he says the ultimate goal of Bushido is to recognize when, where, how, and for what you should die.

Though I’ve never seen a carp placed on a cutting board, we use this simile for various 
occasions for facing predicament and requiring rational judgment / action in such a way; “The company is considering a massive layoff, I’m a carp on a chopping block,” “The governor behaved like a carp on a chopping block when he was sued for sex scandals,” "My husband said "I'm a carp on a chopping block," when he was told he was at the terminal stage of cancer by his doctor."

Are there metaphoric expressions similar to “a carp laid on a chopping block” which implies keeping composed at eleventh hour, preferably using a bird, beast, or fish, like a carp?

Comment: Of course! The most canonically British expression of all: Keeping a stiff upper lip.

Comment: We have the idiom "cold fish" for someone who shows little emotion, which could apply in some of the scenarios you described. But it's usually used negatively (indicating unfriendliness) rather than positively.

Comment: Non-metaphoric adjectives include *serene* and *imperturbable*.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91439/adjective-for-terrified-yet-calm-and-capable also, in my opinion, the best word for this *equanimity*, though it is not metaphorical

Comment: ...and if you want an English-speaking-world analogy that typifies "stiff upper lip", similar to the noble carp, how about **"Like the band who kept playing as the Titanic sank"**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[*Nerves of steel*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/nerve) connotes the ability to control your fear and remain calm even in extremely dangerous or difficult situations.

Lionhearted, courage of a lion, etc. are also used to connote bravery.

Comment: It’s difficult for a non-native English speaker to weigh which of ‘Stiff upper lips’ and ‘Nerves of steel’ is closer to ‘carps on the chopping block.” as a metaphor of staying calm and rational at the panicky situation. So I had to toss the coin to accept the latter. To me ‘lionhearted” is more focused on ‘courage and bravery’ than ‘calmness and self-composure’ as you admit.

Comment: To me, *nerves of steel* is typically associated with bold actions (e.g. "That trapeze artist has nerves of steel!"), where *stiff upper lip* is more frequently found associated with emotional circumstances. "Your dog died, mate? Keep a stiff upper lip!"

Comment: Along the same lines, saying that someone is "steel and velvet" is not just keeping their cool under stress, but also keeping their manners.

Comment: @Wayne, agreed completely. Secret agent James Bond needs _nerves of steel_ not to soil his trousers when the minions of evil super-criminals are chasing him with various highly lethal weaponry at their disposal. But once he gets back to MI5 and has to explain to M why he’s caused £340 million worth of damage to the historic centre of Athens and destroyed the Parthenon, he needs to keep a _stiff upper lip_ and appear unperturbed.

Answer (score 45):

The idiom most used in British English is to maintain a *stiff upper lip*.

It means to retain composure in the face of adversity.  A trembling lip is a sign of weakness.

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as "metaphoric" (but I could be wrong).

Comment: @PatrickT we don't physically have stiff upper lips.

Comment: stiff: "not easily bent or changed in shape", I can make mine stiff, but perhaps it's like wiggling ears, not everyone can ;-)

Answer (score 31):

The phrases *grace under fire* and *cool under fire* are both used to convey calm in a difficult situation. *Under fire* refers to gunfire and the phrase was well adapted to the movie titled [*Courage Under Fire*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115956/).

For an animal idiom, consider *like a lamb led to slaughter*. This is a phrase from the Judeo-Christian Bible, [Isaiah 53:7](http://biblehub.com/isaiah/53-7.htm)

> He was oppressed, and he was afflicted, yet he opened not his mouth; *like a lamb that is led to the slaughter*, and like a sheep that before its shearers is silent, so he opened not his mouth.

Comment: Huh, I usually hear *like a lamb led to slaughter* implying naivete, unawareness of the danger that one is in. Didn't realize that the original source used it for someone very aware of the danger.

Comment: Maybe it's because I *did* know the origin, but I never associated it with unawareness (though I can see how that could be perceived).  To me, this phrase conveys that the person went into a fatal situation willingly or without resisting.

Comment: "Cool under pressure" is another good one that's related to the above.

Comment: +1 for grace under fire, -2 for lamb led to slaughter. Lamb led to slaughter refers to the calmness that comes from being foolish.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat And do you think the carp in the OP's question is being wise?

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat - I don't think anyone in the Judeo-Christian tradition would agree about *lamb to the slaughter* being foolish - I think most understand it as meekness and humility.

Comment: Now that I re-read the OP and think about it more, I believe that "lamb to the slaughter" is the best choice (though it does carry the idea that one is being unjustly persecuted, as opposed to simply being in a difficult situation)

Comment: _Lamb to the slaughter_ says to me that the person is **resigned to their fate**, and not taking cool, calm, and collected action to extricate themselves.

Comment: "7 He was oppressed and He was afflicted, Yet He did not open His mouth; Like a lamb that is led to slaughter, And like a sheep that is silent before its shearers, So He did not open His mouth." I think the sheep getting sheared is meek, the sheep about to get slaughtered is foolish.

Comment: @PhilPerry Well, yeah - do you think the carp's trying to extricate himself from the chopping block?

Answer (score 29):

To remain " as cool as a cucumber " is an idiomatic expression used to indicate a controlled composure in front a a difficult event.

Comment: Strikes me as a little "silly" for a serious or dangerous situation.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161778/he-remained-cool-as-a-cucumber

Comment: @KRyan So does "a carp laid on a chopping block", in my opinion.

Comment: "Cool as a cucumber" refers to general demeanour and is not specific at all to dangerous situations or 'a difficult event' as indicated by the original post.

Comment: @nathanchere I disagree, I think it is specific to difficult (though not necessarily dangerous) situations. It describes demeanour at a point in time, not generally.

Comment: News Headline: "General Lee as cool as cucumber as confederacy surrenders."

Answer (score 10):

Surprised nobody mentioned *stoic*, since its OED definition is "a person who can endure pain or hardship without showing their feelings or complaining."

Other things not mentioned:

- *put on a brave face*
- *grin and bear it*

Comment: I was surprised to have to search for "Stoic", +1

Answer (score 9):

Consider also "sangfroid" (which I've also seen as "sang-froid") - http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sangfroid

From the French meaning "cold blood" it refers to staying calm in a difficult situation.

Comment: Related to that (cold blood), there are also the term "ice in the veins," meaning a person who stays cool under pressure ("Joe has ice in his veins"), or the word "frosty" which is used to mean the same in some circles ("stay frosty").

Comment: I don't know the precise connotation of *sangfroid* in French, but in English, *cold blooded* means emotionless, not the ability to control one's emotions. Cold blooded is often used to describe acts of cruelty.

Comment: @medica - Indeed, but I don't believe that "emotionless" or "heartless" is the meaning of "sangfroid" (as an English import word, or indeed in the original French).
I think that its meaning is best expressed in opposition to "hot" idioms, rather than in commonality with "cold": it's the opposite of being hot-tempered, hot-blooded, acting in the heat of the moment, etc.

Comment: @almcnicoll - good point. I didn't think to look at it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There are some English words with that meaning:

**imperturbable**: *incapable of being upset or agitated; not easily excited; calm.*

**cool-headed**: *not easily worried or excited.*

**placid**: *(of a person or animal) not easily upset or excited.*

Of these I would say that "imperturbable" is the most emphatic, but it is not commonly used.  The most casual of these is "cool-headed," and that is also the only one of the three that specifically connotates calmness *under fire*, I think; the others are more about general temperament.

If you are looking for a multi-word expression that you are likely to hear in conversation, "cool as a cucumber" is what comes to mind for me.

Comment: As an alternative to "imperturbable", I like "unflappable".

Comment: Ah yes -- I had forgotten that one!

Answer (score 5):

*Keeping your head when others are losing theirs* 
*Keep your head about you*

All variations of Rudyard Kipling's quote:

*If you can keep your wits about you while all others are losing theirs, and blaming you. The world will be yours and everything in it, what's more, you'll be a man, my son.*

Answer (score 5):

In sports, we use the word "clutch." A player is clutch if they can perform in a high risk/stress situation, like hitting a last second shot to win a playoff game.  Players that are not clutch break down in those situations.

Edit: this is a much more slang type of term as well.

Answer (score 4):

Consider "[(as) cool as a cat](http://books.google.fr/books?id=q7jBsomnGSUC&pg=PT111&lpg=PT111&dq=%22Cool+as+a+cat%22&source=bl&ots=EXma3p2xwd&sig=EG2Ex-uvtBSCpboQi8aiXnoQ5RE&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=-pBFU-6nLKj00gXS5YGYBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Cool%20as%20a%20cat%22&f=false)."

> [cool as a cat](http://www.finedictionary.com/cat.html): to act fine when you are actually scared or nervous.

Consider also "[to keep one's cool](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/keep+one%27s+cool)" and "[to keep one's chin up](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/keep+one%27s+chin+up)."

> [keep one's chin up](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=I0PlgdHnLVIC&pg=PA217&lpg=PA217&dq=%22but+he+kept+his+chin+up%22&source=bl&ots=K_w_gMzjus&sig=5YfbiHLrbNFYXN_XvtURzhmm6cY&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=U7pFU_TxGOSO0AX38IDYCg&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=%22but%20he%20kept%20his%20chin%20up%22&f=false): to be brave; be determined: face trouble with courage.

Comment: Frankly, no cat i've ever seen or had could be described as "cool as a cat".  :)

Comment: @cHao Check this out http://www.petplace.com/cats/why-are-cats-so-independent/page1.aspx :-)

Comment: cool as a cat is used often, don't know why the down vote.  I believe it came from the jazz scene when they called more relaxed people "cats".

Comment: I've never heard "as cool as a cat" used in this way. A "cool cat", sure, meaning someone who is trendy or hip, but not "as cool as a cat" meaning acting fine when you're nervous.

Comment: These would have been good answers if it was ELU 70s edition.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd That's right. Didn't I ever tell you I'm a downright 70s revivalist?

Comment: I am just thinking your English books are a bit outdated.  My wife is French and went to university for English and she said a lot of the things she learned were a little dated and didn't figure it out until she came to the US.

Answer (score 3):

I will offer two modern (chilly) variations:

- ice cold

> to be in a state of complete self control
>
> usually a referance to staying cool enough to not sport wood in the
>   presence of a fine lady "just stay cool man, ice cold"

- stone cold

> 2) emotionless

And a variation of other answers not mentioned and probably the most generic term I hear - **keep(ing) your cool**.

Comment: Steve Austin!!!

Comment: @AbraCadaver - who is better under pressure other than Stone Cold?

Answer (score 2):

There's a solid as a rock which isn't used/heard much anymore.   I've always like unflappable when in the face of severe circumstances or 'shaken not stirred'.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with *composed*. He maintained a composed demeanour in the face of the terrible news.

Answer (score 2):

The apt translation to English is ***dead man walking***. Like the Japanese expression, this phrase has a literal meaning from which the figurative meaning derives.

### Literal meaning

Traditionally, a prison warden would call this out while leading a man to the place of execution. The English expression connotes a similar poise or self-control as of the carp in the Japanese expression. For all intents and purposes, the man is dead, except that the actual stroke of execution has not occurred. Knowing this, the man still walks to the place where he will die.

### Figurative meaning

Like the Japanese expression, the English expression is used figuratively of a person who in any hopeless situation is completing his final tasks. For example, a person who cannot avoid losing his job and yet is in the process of completing his remaining work assignments is ***dead man walking***. The expression can be applied to one’s self, or to others. It is also sometimes used to describe a person in a hopeless situation who does not know it (yet).

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dead+man+walking

Comment: I don't believe that "dead man walking" has any connotation of stoicism in the face of execution - I have only ever seen it in the context of "as good as dead". Can you cite examples of "dead man walking" implying the demeanour of the person faced with death?

Answer (score 1):

There is also ["face the music"](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/face-the-music.html) which basically means to own up to the inevitable.

Perhaps more applicable, ["bite the bullet"](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/bite-the-bullet.html), the origin of which is perhaps that a soldier when being whipped would have a bullet (lead ball at the time) in their mouth and bite on that to bear the pain so they could show no outward emotion.

Answer (score 1):

Something like *[balls of steel](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=balls%20of%20steel)* (if we are talking about informal speech).

Answer (score 0):

If you are telling a story about such a situation you might say

> I collected myself

or

> I composed myself

If you handled the pressure, someone might describe you as being

> calm and collected

Comment: Implying that you are resigned to your fate. I'm not sure that's what the OP was referring to.

Comment: @PhilPerry It doesn't imply that.

Comment: By itself, to "collect yourself" or "compose yourself" _usually_ is taken to mean that you've accepted your fate, and to stop fighting. With more elaboration on what you're doing to fight, they could mean what you say.

Answer (score 0):

"Never loses his cool" or "Always keeps his cool"

Answer (score 0):

Surprised no one has mentioned:

> Unflinching - "Not showing fear or hesitation in the face of danger or
>   difficulty."

Which can also be combined with courage and composure:

> He showed unflinching courage.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, depending on the context, "whistling past the graveyard" or "he whistled as he walked past the graveyard", implying that even though he was afraid to walk past it, he put on a brave face and walked on anyway, not only to look fearless to others, but to try to convince *himself* that he isn't afraid. It's sort of an old-fashioned phrase though, so modern readers might not quite understand it.

Answer (score 0):

*Keeping a cool head* means this and keeps the idea of 'head'.

Answer (score 0):

The import term '[savoir faire](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/171476)' refers to emotional composure in a difficult social situation:

> Knowledge of the correct course of action in a particular situation, know-how. Now usually: *spec*. the ability to act or speak appropriately in social situations.

Answer (score -4):

"Deer in the headlights" conveys being immobile in the face of imminent peril.

Comment: That's just the opposite of composure, though.